# CordovaLibのファイルが存在しないエラー発生

Tags: android, html5, android-studio, cordova, gradle

こんにちは

android studio + cordovaで開発しています。
ビルドで下記エラーとなり、CordovaLib内のエラーで対処できない状態です。
エラーはokhttp関連のエラーがかなり多く出ています。

ご教授いただけると助かります。

C:\Users\app\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\com\squareup\okhttp\Address.java:18: エラー: パッケージcom.squareup.okhttp.internalは存在しません
import com.squareup.okhttp.internal.Util;
                                   ^
C:\Users\app\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\com\squareup\okhttp\Address.java:25: エラー: パッケージcom.squareup.okhttp.internalは存在しません

Answer (score 0):

もしかしてJava6を使用されていますか？okhttpはJava7以上を必要としているため、Java6環境ではエラーになってしまうようです。使用するJavaのバージョンを7以降にして再度試してみてはいかがでしょうか。

okhttpのGitHubのページにて同様の事象に関するIssueが上がっていました。

[okhttp fails to build when complies with Java version 1.6 for android · Issue #528 · square/okhttp · GitHub](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/528)

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。

Comment: JAVAは、７と８で試しましたが、同じでした

Comment: @road さんの状況がわかりませんが、importのところでエラーが出ているので、クラスパスの問題かもしれません。

例えば、Gradleのcompileの記述を加え済であるのに、okhttpのjarをダウンロードしてどこかに配置しパスを通している(=結果的に二重にパスを通そうとしてしまっている)、とか。

どのようにokhttpのライブラリにパスを通しているのか記載していただけると解決に近づけるかもしれませんね。 okhttpのreadmeも必要に応じて見てみてください。 [GitHub - square/okhttp: An HTTP+HTTP/2 client for Android and Java applications](https://github.com/square/okhttp)